# Why discarded values are () instead of ⊥ in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Howcome in Haskell, when there is a value that would be discarded, `()` is used instead of `⊥`?

Examples (can't really think of anything other than IO actions at the moment):

```
mapM_ :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
foldM_ :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m ()
writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
```

Under strict evaluation, this makes perfect sense, but in Haskell, it only makes the domain bigger.

Perhaps there are "unused parameter" functions `d -> a` which are strict on `d` (where `d` is an unconstrained type parameter and does not appear free in `a`)? Ex: `seq`, `const' x y = y`seq`x`.

Comment: For most everyday Haskell programming, we like to pretend there is no such thing as `_|_`... we only whip that out when in the more formal mode.  I.e. we like to pretend that `data Foo = A | B` only has two possible values instead of three; so there is only one value of type `()`.  You could throw the term "fully defined" in there if you like.

Comment: What would the alternative be? i.e. what's a sensible type for `writeFile` or `mapM_`?

Comment: @dbaupp: `writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> a`, `mapM_ :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m z`

Comment: @Longpoke, you'd need a `Monad` constraint in the first one, otherwise it could be used in pure code.

Comment: @dbaupp: typo. writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO a

Comment: Listen to @luqui, he's given you the answer.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is because you need to specify the type of the value to be discarded.  In Haskell-98, `()` is the obvious choice.  And as long as you know the type is `()`, you may as well make the value `()` as well (presuming evaluation proceeds that far), just in case somebody tries to pattern-match on it or something.  I think most programmers don't like introducing extra ⊥'s into code because it's just an extra trap to fall into.  I certainly avoid it.

Instead of `()`, it is possible to create an uninhabited type (except by ⊥ of course).

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

data Void

mapM_ :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m Void
```

Now it's not even possible to pattern-match, because there's no `Void` constructor.  I suspect the reason this isn't done more often is because it's not Haskell-98 compatible, as it requires the EmptyDataDecls extension.

Edit:  you can't pattern-match on Void, but `seq` will ruin your day.  Thanks to @sacundim for pointing this out.

Comment: I wonder if `Void` will be used for such things in "Haskell Prime". Are there any downsides (besides breaking backwards compatibility) of using `Void` in this way, instead of `()`?

Comment: @DanBurton - none that I can see, although introducing it for all the standard libs would be a major change so I think it's unlikely to happen.

Comment: @JohnL: +1, but I don't think that `Void` is valid replacment for `()`. `()` signalizes there's exactly one value (and as such it doesn't carry any additional information), on the other hand `Void` signalizes the lack of value. It also plays nice with logic - you can always consturct value of the trivially-true type `⊤` (the fact that Haskell isn't consistent under CH is another thing). If anything, we should probably force pattern matching on non `m ()` (even if that means having to write `_ <-` to explicitly ignore the value); it makes the code a bit safer.

Comment: @JohnL Ok, now write `mapM_` without using bottom :-)

Comment: @sclv: `void :: Void;void = error "void value used (probably by a strictness annotation)"; 
mapM_' f xs = mapM_ f xs >> return void;` @JohnL, I'm not sure what you mean by "pattern matching on non `m ()`"

Comment: @Longpoke: Read [Do notation considered harmful](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Do_notation_considered_harmful), section 1.3.

Comment: @Vitus: I agree completely, `Void` and `()` are separate types with different uses.  For the specific case of `mapM_` returning `m Void`, I'm not enough of a logician to go through the full implications of it, however off the cuff it does seem semantically sensible, as the information provided by the `()` is simply that the calculation terminated.  If it doesn't terminate, you'd find that out upon binding or running the monad anyway.  And from an operational perspective, more `Void`s seems to have potential for better code generation.  @sclv: you got me there :)

Comment: @Longpoke: `error` is ⊥.  The only way to make a value with `Void` type is by using ⊥ in some form.  The program will never try to evaluate it, but you've used it.  Unless, for the purpose of this argument, `unsafeCoerce 0` doesn't count as ⊥?

Comment: Yeah I forgot sclv said "without using bottom", but when I wrote this question, I was imagining using ⊥ directly instead of (). I don't consider `unsafe*` at all.

Comment: There's a [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.5.1) that provides a Haskell98 compliant implementation of Void.

Comment: I mean there is a very obvious reason not to use `Void`. For all intents and purposes `Void` is `forall a. a` due to the `absurd` function with type `forall a. Void -> a`. So you could do something like `(\`asTypeOf\` 'x') . absurd <$> mapM_ pure [()]`. Which is not a reasonable thing to do, but is well typed. The whole point of `Void` is that you CANNOT make it, that is the reason it was created and the reason the functions that operate on it are sensible, even considering just making a bunch of `Void` values via `undefined` is crazy.

Answer (score 10):

Well, bottom type literally means an unterminating computation, and unit type is just what it is - a type inhabited with single value. Clearly, monadic computations usually meant to be finished, so it simply doesn't make sense to make them return `undefined`. And, of course, it is simply a safety measure - just like John L said, what if someone pattern matches on monadic result? So monadic computations return the 'lowest' possible (in Haskell 98) type - unit.

Comment: ⊥ isn't necessarily nontermination, pattern match failure is also ⊥, for example.

Comment: I guess if you define `print' :: Show a => a -> IO z; print' a = print a >> return undefined`, `print' 'a' >>= \"blah" -> print' 'b'` will compile and fail at runtime. Using an empty sum type as John L wrote would fix this.

Comment: @Longpoke: pattern match failure and similar errors are also considered nontermination in Haskell's semantics.

Comment: @sacundim I see ⊥ as "failure to evaluate to a well-defined value of the expression's type". Nontermination, pattern match failures, explicitly thrown  exceptions, out of memory errors, power failure kills the machine; all of these are just categorisation of different kinds of ⊥. You can say that a power failure is considered nontermination, but I'd rather say that nontermination and power failure are both kinds of ⊥; they're indistinguishable from the point of view of Haskell's pure semantics, but you can tell from outside by whether the program hangs or the monitor goes black.

Comment: No, I would have to insist that power failure is not a form of ⊥. Why? Because the semantics of Haskell is clearly intended to be compositional: the denotation of an expression is a function of the denotation of its subparts. Since evaluation of any expression is nondeterministically subject to a power failure, then the semantics would have to say that every expression nondeterministically denots either its true value or ⊥—which is clearly not right.

Comment: @sacundim On reflection you're right. I should only include *deterministic* failures in that list. Nondeterminstic failures only show up when you're thinking operationally; `1 + 1` always *means* `2`, though on any particular run something may go wrong to prevent the system from computing that result (this failure is only observable from within `IO` or outside the system). I'd still rather think of nontermination as a kind of ⊥ than think of pattern match failure as a form of nontermination.

Comment: @Ben, although you might be able to tell that the computer is burning power, it's the surrounding I/O operation that is doing that rather than the bottom expression. If it were the expression itself then parsing would hang, and maybe even the text editor as you're typing the expression. For a bottom expression, the I/O that rotates the value into a delta-entropy distributed over spacetime hangs and the value of the expression is unknowable.

Answer (score 9):

So, maybe we could have the following signatures:

```
mapM_     :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m z
foldM_    :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m z
writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO z
```

We'd reimplement the functions in question so that any attempt to bind the `z` in `m z` or `IO z` would bind the variable to `undefined` or any other bottom.

What do we gain?  Now people can write programs that force the `undefined` result of these computations.  How is that a good thing?  All it means is that people can now write programs that fail to terminate for no good reason, that were impossible to write before.

Comment: These failing programs aren't impossible to write now.  You can always introduce ⊥.  But I upvoted because you reminded me of something I overlooked.

Answer (score 8):

You're getting confused between types and values.

In `writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()`, the `()` is the unit *type*. The value you get for `x` by doing `x <- writeFile foo bar` in a do block is (normally) the *value* `()`, which is the sole non-bottom inhabitant of the type `()`.

`⊥` OTOH is a *value*. Since `⊥` is a member of every type, it's also usable as a value for the type `()`. If you're discarding that `x` above without using it (we normally don't even extract it into a variable), it may very well be `⊥` and you'd never know. In that sense you already have what you want; if you're ever writing a function whose result you expect to be always ignored, you could use `⊥`. But since `⊥` is a value of every type, there is no type `⊥`, and so there is no type `IO ⊥`.

But really, they represent different conceptual things. The type `()` is the type of values that contain zero information (which is why there is only one value; if there were two or more values then `()` values would contain at least as much information as values of `Bool`). `IO ()` is the type of IO actions that generate a value with no information, but may effects that will happen as a result of generating that non-informative value.

`⊥` is in some sense a non-value. `` 1 `div` 0 `` gives `⊥` because there is no value that could be used as the result of that expression which satisfies the laws of integer division. Throwing an exception gives `⊥` because functions that contain exception throws do not give you a value of their type. Non-termination gives `⊥` because the expression never terminates with a value. `⊥` is a way of treating all of these non-values as if they were a value for some purposes. As far as I can tell it's mainly useful because Haskell's laziness means that `⊥` and a data structure containing `⊥` (i.e. `[⊥]`) are distinguishable.

The value `()` is not like the cases where we use `⊥`. `writeFile foo bar` doesn't have an "impossible value" like `` return $ 1 `div` 0 ``, it just has no information in its value (other than that contained in the monadic structure). There are perfectly sensible things I *could* do with the `()` I get from doing `x <- writeFile foo bar`; they're just not very interesting and so nobody ever does them. This is distinctly different from `` x <- return $ 1 `div` 0 ``, where doing anything with that value has to give me another ill-defined value.

Comment: By "⊥" as a type, I meant any type that can only have ⊥ as a value, such as `a` in `Integer -> a`, or the "Void" type in John's answer

Comment: This is the only answer that IMO really makes clear the conceptual difference between "only one value" (i.e. `Void`) and "only one *defined* value" (i.e. `()`). To me, that's what the question is all about.

Comment: I find 1/0 gives Infinity, not ⊥.

Comment: @TorosFanny That's what I get for not checking my examples! If you use integer math it does what I claim, so ``1 `div` 0``.

Comment: @Ben Yes, but this mistake is misleading. Could I fix it?

Comment: @TorosFanny I agree, so I already have. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

`()` is `⊤`, i.e. the [unit type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type), not the `⊥` (the [bottom type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type)). The big difference is that the unit type is inhabited, so that it has a value (`()` in Haskell), on the other hand, the bottom type is uninhabited, so that you can't write functions like that:

```
absurd : ⊥
absurd = -- no way
```

Of course you can do this in Haskell since the "bottom type" (there is no such thing, of course) is inhabited here with `undefined`. This makes Haskell inconsistent.

Functions like this:

```
disprove : a → ⊥
disprove x = -- ...
```

can be written, it is the same as

```
disprove : ¬ a
disprove x = -- ...
```

i.e. it disproving the type `a`, so that `a` is an absurd.

In any case, you can see how the unit type is used in different languages, as `() :: ()` in Haskell, `() : unit` in ML, `() : Unit` in Scala and `tt : ⊤` in Agda. In languages like Haskell and Agda (with the IO monad) functions like `putStrLn` should have a type `String → IO ⊤`, not the `String → IO ⊥` since this is an absurd (logically it states that there is no strings that can be printed, this is just not right).

---

**DISCLAIMER**: previous text use [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) notation and it is more about Agda than Haskell.

In Haskell if we have

```
data Void
```

It doesn't mean that `Void` is uninhabited. It is inhabited with `undefined`, non-terminating programs, errors and exceptions. For example:

```
data Void

instance Show Void where
  show _ = "Void"

data Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }

mapM__ :: (a -> Identity b) -> [a] -> Identity Void
mapM__ _ _ = Identity undefined
```

then

```
print $ runIdentity $ mapM__ (const $ Identity 0) [1, 2, 3]
-- ^ will print "Void".
case runIdentity $ mapM__ (const $ Identity 0) [1, 2, 3] of _ -> print "1"
-- ^ will print "1".
let x = runIdentity $ mapM__ (const $ Identity 0) [1, 2, 3]
x `seq` print x
-- ^ will thrown an exception.
```

But it also doesn't mean that `Void` is ⊥. So

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m Void
```

where `Void` is decalred as empty data type, is ok. But

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ⊥
```

is nonsence, but there is no such type as ⊥ in Haskell.

Comment: Also if you allow `mapM_ : ∀ {A B M} → RawMonad M → (A → M B) → List A → M ⊥`, you can write `absurd : ⊥ ; absurd = mapM_ IdentityMonad id []`.

Comment: @Vitus, right, also it's true for every monad M for which `runM : M A → A` can be written. Maybe not for `IO`. In fact, `IO ⊥` can be inhabited. Since IO is an abstract type this is depending on it implementation.

Comment: The question specifically mentions Haskell and this answer uses non-Haskell notation and refers to non-Haskell concepts, I find it somewhat confusing. Also, you said that `String → IO ⊥` means that no strings can be printed, but I don't see that – surely it just means you can't do anything *after* printing a string? (for example, it would be legitimate for `forever` to have type `m a -> m Void`)

Comment: Also, what on earth do you mean when you say the bottom type is inhabited, but also doesn't exist?

Comment: Hi @Ben . This answer uses Agda notation. Haskell is inconsistent sometimes, Agda is consistent and _closely_ related to Haskell, so IMHO it is a good thing to peek on Agda when thinking about such theoretic issues. About `String → IO ⊥`. I suppose that `IO ⊥` is uninhabited. It is a question though, one can implement `IO` to have some nullary constructor like `emptyIO :: IO a`, then `putStrLn :: String → IO ⊥` or `foreverIO :: IO a → IO ⊥` would be ok. But if `IO ⊥` is uninhabited, then for the function `foo :: String → IO ⊥` the term `foo "whatever"` would be an absurd.

Comment: @Ben about `bottom type is inhabited` and `doesn't exist`. In Haskell you can write `undefined :: Void` or `error "Void" :: Void` or `a = a` and then `a :: Void` and so on, where `Void` is the data type from `Data.Void` or just an empty type declaration like `data Void;`. So this is not the right bottom :) It is inhabited with undefined values, errors and non-terminating programs.

Comment: @Ben also see the example by Vitus. Generally it is natural to have unit type here. Bottom type can cause problems.

Comment: I would argue that the inconsistency of Haskell is somewhat significant in this question - the fact that `Void` is inhabited seems to make it usable in these cases, precisely because the ability to define `absurd` is not obviously a problem. So if you are going to make an analogy with Agda, you ought to say that you are doing so and establish why that is a legitimate thing to do. Heck, it's probably a good idea to at least say what Agda *is*. Also I find reason to believe that `IO Void` is inhabited by defined values - e.g. look at `throwIO`.

Comment: @Ben let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13193/discussion-between-ht-and-ben-millwood).

Comment: Subsequent to your edits, I removed my downvote: your answer is no longer outright misleading. Still not sure I actively *like* it though (see the chat).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out one *severe* downside to writing one *particular* form of returning ⊥: if you write types like this, you get bad programs:

```
mapM_ :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m z
```

This is *way* too polymorphic. As an example, consider `forever :: Monad m => m a -> m b`. I encountered this gotcha a long time ago and I'm still bitter:

```
main :: IO ()
main = forever putStrLn "This is going to get printed a lot!"
```

The error is obvious and simple: missing parentheses.

- It *typechecks*. This is exactly the sort of error that the type system is supposed to catch easily.
- It *silently infinite loops at runtime* (without printing anything). It is a pain to debug.

Why? Well, because `r ->` is a monad. So `m b` matches virtually *anything*. For example:

```
forever :: m a -> m b
forever putStrLn :: String -> b
forever putStrLn "hello!" :: b -- eep!
forever putStrLn "hello" readFile id flip (Nothing,[17,0]) :: t -- no type error.
```

This sort of thing inclines me to the view that `forever` should be typed `m a -> m Void`.

Comment: If `forever :: Monad m => m a -> m Void` then `x` in `x <- forever ...` would not make any sense. And it's right because `forever` cannot return. `forever :: Monad m => m a -> m ()` solve the problem as well, but `x` in `x <- forever ...` would be `()`, maybe it's not right.

Comment: `()` would be an improvement over just `b`, but conceptually `Void` is correct, I think, since indeed `x <- forever ...` will never give a value to `x` (as the original polymorphic type witnesses!)